# UITableView Section Footer Text with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that has a number of sections with varying numbers of rows which have been created dynamically.

I would like to add footer text to certain sections of my UITableView. I know this is easily done when implementing static UITableViews (see image), but I am having difficulty programmatically adding footer text in Swift.

[image: Footer text added to a static UITableViewSection]

I am aware of how to add titles to each section.

Comment: "but I am having difficulty" That's a pity, but it isn't a question. What's the question? If you're aware that text is displayed by a label, why are you unable to add a label to your section footer? Show your code and explain the problem _you_ are having with this.

Comment: And you really don't see how to do that? Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Unless the answer is written so that it can just be used instead of an answer that helps in the right direction, it's not good enough I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement UITableViewDelegate protocol method:

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int)
```

*Just don't forget to set the delegate first.

Answer (score 1):

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String?

Comment: Can you explain how this is really any different than the accepted answer from 3 years ago?

Comment: Accepted answer return view. You can place in that view whatever you want but my answer returns title exactly.

Answer (score 0):

See the UITableViewDelegate documentation under "Modifying Header and Footer of sections"

```
tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
```

Asks the delegate for a view object for a view object to display in the footer of the specified section.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question?